# Clarification in edit rejection

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I recently tried to [add a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24950262) to an old question I thought was fitting. I had the same issue and was pointed to the solution by the answer, so I thought I'd tag the software causing the error so it was easier for others to find in the future.

One edit rejection doesn't seem to fit IMO ("deviates from the original intent of the post"), but the other one has me confused:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

The question is really about a row lock in a Progress database. If I understand the reason correctly, the [openquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openquery) tag should really be replaced with the [progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress) tag because it is only how the OP is trying to access the Progress database that is causing the error. "Progress" is literally in the error message.

Am I misunderstanding the reason here?

Comment: The reasons used here are wrong. Adding a tag to a post doesn't improve it, so reviewers should've chosen the reason 'no improvement whatsoever'.

Comment: @double-beep That's fair, but wouldn't adding the appropriate tag for the error improve the question? I was getting nearly the same error and I am not using OpenQuery, I was working with odbc in php

Comment: @double You mean the `progress` tag does not apply to that question? I would say it does, but I'm certainly not an expert.

Comment: @yivi no, I meant it's not a suggested edit that should've been approved because there were other issues with the post which could've been fixed (e.g. code and error formatting).

Comment: @double Tag only edits are allowed. There is nothing wrong with the error formatting. Code formatting could be improved, but I do not think that's enough of a reason to reject an edit. Particularly for a _suggested_ edit, where code edits are generally discouraged. It would be "no improvement" if the question was close-worthy, but if not, we should accept improvements. Even more so with tagging, which help question discovery. And I would certainly not say *no improvement whatsoever*.